# Pyomo sparse set not working in constraint

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a variable `model.x` in my Pyomo Concrete Model with four indices (`model.Biomass`, `model.SourceCounty`,`model.ProdCounty`, and `model.Year`). The total possible combinations of these four indices is over 90 million. This results in long run times and excess memory usage. I'm only concerned about a subset of the potential combinations of indices, `model.x_index`, which I use to define `model.x` in the code below.

```
# create subset of four sets of indices
model.x_index = Set(initialize=[(a, i, j, y) for a in model.Biomass for i in model.SourceCounty for j in model.ProdCounty
                                for y in model.Year if model.TD[i, j] < 1000 and model.BP[a, i, y] > 0
                                and model.FP[a, i, y] < 1000])

# create decision variable x
model.x = Var(model.x_index, domain=PositiveReals)
```

I am running into an issue with one of my constraints, `model.feedstock_total`, which I define below. The input to this constraint are three of the four indices (all of the possible values, not just the ones in `model.x_index`). I create a subset `subset` within the constraint of all values of `model.x_index` with the three arguments `a`, `i`, and `y` equal to the inputs `feed`, `county`, and `year`. For some of the potential inputs `feed`, `county`, and `year`, the subset will be empty because these combinations are not in `model.x_index`. For these cases, I want the constraint to exit (`Constraint.Skip`) and move on to the next possible set of inputs.

```
def feedstock_total_rule(model, feed, county, year):
    subset = {(a, i, prodcounty, y) for (a, i, prodcounty, y) in model.x_index if a == feed and i == county and y == year}
    if len(subset) == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return sum(model.x[m] for m in subset) <= model.BP[feed, county, year]


model.feedstock_total = Constraint(model.Biomass, model.SourceCounty, model.Year, rule=feedstock_total_rule)
```

The issue I am running into is that my model is timing out when I put a time limit on how long to solve and the error thrown is that the model is trying to index `model.x` in this constraint with an invalid index (i.e., a combination of the four indices that isn't part of `model.x_index`). I don't know why it's trying to do this because it should be creating an empty set and then calling `Constraint.Skip`. I've tried running all of these lines individually in the console, and all of them are running fine (i.e., `model.x_index` and `model.x` are created with no issues, the `subset` is created with no issues and is length 0 when appropriate).

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on here? I'm really at a loss.

Comment: The error should spit out the "invalid index" for inspection, no?  If it does, have you checked it?  If it doesn't, can you edit your post to show the error trace?

Comment: I'm now getting no error output -- the code just fails to run in the time limit I set, which should be sufficient for the model to solve. Do you have any advice for debugging? I tried inserting error messages in both parts of the constraint (the if and else) and it is correctly triggering those a couple of minutes in, so it's obviously calculating the sets correctly. But then it fails to complete the entire model.

Comment: Does `Constraint.Skip` skip just that iteration of the constraint or the constraint in general?

Comment: Is there another phrase besides `Constraint.Skip` I can use, like `return 1 == 1`, I can use? I have another constraint that I ran with the model with (without this problematic constraint) that has identical syntax and solves in <30 minutes. The only difference is that in the constraint that solves, the `if len(subset) == 0` condition is never met, so I'm thinking that the `Constraint.Skip` condition is what's preventing it from solving.

Comment: Exactly what part is so time-consuming? It take that long while creating or solving the model?
Solving the model should not be a problem, but creating the LP model to be solved may be harsh since you need to iterate along all `prodcounty` index each time per index

Comment: `Constraint.Skip` should skip the contraint in the given index that `if` statement is activated

Comment: There is no time limit on model construction time, so that is not it. You could simply insert a print statement before commanding the solver to measure the construction time. Check the number of elements in the constraint, etc.  chop 90% of the data out of your model and see if you can get something working

Comment: Can you help me with what code to run to check number of elements in the constraint or to measure the construction time? I’m new to Pyomo and the handbook I’ve found with the basics isn’t helping with that.

Comment: `Constraint.Skip` is correct here, that isn't the problem.  It is too difficult to T/S this without the whole model.  You may be running out of memory or who knows...  I suggest you make a copy of your data, chop it down to a minimal example, and see if you can get it to run

Comment: Turns out that time limit was the issue. I found another way to create the subset that uses significantly less memory/time and is able to solve now. It uses only one for loop and one if statement instead of one for loop and three if statements. `subset = {(feed, county, j, year) for j in model.ProdCounty if (feed, county, j, year) in model.x_index}` Hopefully this alternate formulation can help anyone else working on sparse set issues in Pyomo.